# Error al cargar vista en MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo un error al llenar unos textbox con mvc

> El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsumirAPI.Models.EmpModel]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'ConsumirAPI.Models.EmpModel'.

controlador

```html
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            List<EmpModel> EmpInfo = new List<EmpModel>();

            using (var client=new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("api/Home/ObtenerEmpleadoId?Id="+id);

                if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var EmpResponse = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmpModel>>(EmpResponse);
                }

                return View(EmpInfo);
            }
        }
```

vista

```html
@model ConsumirAPI.Models.EmpModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>EmpModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Metodos en webApi

```html
        public List<EmpModel> ObtenerEmpleadoId(int Id)
        {
            var rows = er.GetEmpById(Id);
            return rows;
        }
```

```html
        public List<EmpModel> GetEmpById(int id)
        {
            connection();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select *from Employee where Id=@id", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            List<EmpModel> lst = new List<EmpModel>();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                EmpModel em = new EmpModel();
                em.Id = Convert.ToInt16(row["Id"]);
                em.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["FirstName"]);
                em.LastName = Convert.ToString(row["LastName"]);
                em.Company = Convert.ToString(row["Company"]);
                lst.Add(em);
            }

            return lst;
        }
```

Comment: ¿Realmente estás pasando una lista de empleados?

Comment: @fredyfx si, ya agregue tambien el codigo de los metodos del webApi aca arriba y creo que si se esta pasando una lista  o no?

Comment: El problema es que estás recibiendo un solo elemento `@model ConsumirAPI.Models.EmpModel` y en el controlador estás enviando una lista. Por eso te pregunto si estás pasando una lista cuando solo se requiere una clase

Comment: @fredyfx  si, como es por id solo se regresa un solo elemento para llenar los textbox para editar, ¿como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Por que si GetEmpById(int id) devuelve un solo elemento, es del tipo List<EmpModel>. Estás devolviendo una Lista. Está bastante claro el error.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta por que no se como regresar un solo elemento por eso lo puse en una lista

Comment: Esta consulta: `select * from Employee where Id=@id` puede devolver más de un elemento?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta no, solo devuelve uno ya que quiero hacer el edit o update a mi registro

Comment: return View(EmpInfo.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: 2 recomendaciones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY este workshop te ayudará a tener un panorama sobre ASP.net MVC, y para que veas ASP.net Core, revisa la series de 5 posts que tengo en mi blog http://fredyfx.com/blog/

Comment: @AlfredoManuelCanReséndiz funciono con esa instrucción pero no la conozco, seria la única manera de pasar un solo registro a la vista?

Comment: una recomendación adicional: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/ Para que aprendas Entity Framework (en .net y .net core) y eleves el cosmos con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todos los metodos arriba mencionados eran tipo EmpModel y no List<>, y el metodo retorna una entidad EmpModel, por lo que quedaria asi:

controlador

```html
     [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            EmpModel EmpInfo = new EmpModel();

            using (var client=new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("api/Home/ObtenerEmpleadoId?Id="+id);

                if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var EmpResponse = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpModel>(EmpResponse);
                }

                return View(EmpInfo);
            }
        }
```

Metodos en WEBAPI

```html
        [HttpGet]
        public EmpModel ObtenerEmpleadoId(int Id)
        {
            EmpModel rows = er.GetEmpById(Id);
            return rows;
        }
```

```html
        public EmpModel GetEmpById(int id)
        {
            connection();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select *from Employee where Id=@id", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();

            EmpModel em = new EmpModel();
            
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {                
                em.Id = Convert.ToInt16(row["Id"]);
                em.FirstName = Convert.ToString(row["FirstName"]);
                em.LastName = Convert.ToString(row["LastName"]);
                em.Company = Convert.ToString(row["Company"]);                
            }
            
            return em;
        }
```